# Musescore: add dotted 16th note triplet on a dotted 8th note space

Tags: sheet-music, musescore, tuplet

I am trying to transcribe a piece of sheet music in MuseScore.   However, I am having difficulty making a triplet of dotted 16th note.
The music is in 4/4.

[image: bar with dotted 16th notes and a triplet marking]

Can anyone help me with this please?

I have tried [How to create triplets and other tuplets](https://musescore.org/en/node/11186) but still can't understand how to make it work.

Comment: I'm prone to thinking that the triplet is for only the first 2 dotted 16th notes.

Comment: Also, what piece are you trying to transcribe? It's possible that you're notating the rhythm there incorrectly and therefore don't need to ask this question.

Comment: What you are trying to notate is equivalent to writing three sixteenths without a triplet.

Comment: `Ctrl+3` on a quaver, then `.` to get dotted semiquavers.

Answer (score 1):

Using Musescore 3.1.0, I am able to produce triplets from a dotted sixteenth note. First, you should have only two sixteenth notes in your measure, not three. Below is a diagram showing how it is done. Start with two sixteenth notes. Then go to tuplets, and then select triplets and you shoud see the sixteenth note split into three notes with a bracket underneath with a small 3 in the bracket. The first triplet will be the same tone that you clicked on while the other two are shown as rests. Then enter the notes that are desired for the two remaining triplets. You an also cange the first triplet as well, if desired. If this doesn't work I sugest that you reload the Musescore program.

[image: Visual instructions for MuseScore]